В чем различие в unity textTMP и textTMP UGUI?
Создаю сейчас диалоговую систему и столкнулся с этим. Очень буду благодарен, если  кто - то объяснит. В интернете практически ничего про это не нашел

Целый интернет тут и не нужен, потому что есть документация TextMeshPro и TextMeshProUGUI. Если UGUI тебе ничего не говорит, достаточно ознакомиться с оглавлением раздела Properties с право страницы, каждого класса и разница станет очевидна, даже для начинающего.
